# Создание кортежа даты в python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать функцию current_date() так, чтобы программа выводила сегодняшнее число, год и месяц. Нужно использовать strftime()? Как использовать?

```
from datetime import  datetime

def current_date():
    pass
#TODO return month, day, year

m, d, y = current_date()
print("Today's date is: {:2d}/{:2d}/{:4d}".format(m, d, y))
```

Comment: Начните с чтения описания функции - [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime). Там и примеры есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def current_date():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.month, now.day, now.year
```